# angular1.3.7 ng-repeat binding was not expected

Tags: angularjs, forms, data-binding

I'm looking for an explanation of how angular binding works behind the curtain. I only want $scope.values to be updated on ng-click, but once its clicked once it bound to the form forever. woah. Why?

First example is NOT working as I expected it to work. The values should only be reflected in the span everytime I click on my button.

http://jsfiddle.net/webmandman/Ls4g4yLn/12/

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="value in values">{{value.text}}</span><br>
    <input ng-repeat="field in fields" type="text" name="{{field.name}}" ng-model="field.text"/>
</div>
<button ng-click="display()">display</button>

</div>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("myCtrl", function($log,$scope, $http) {
$scope.fields = [
    {name:"Name", text:null},
    {name:"Phone", text:null}
];

$scope.display = function(){
  $log.log("display has been called...");
  $scope.values = $scope.getValues()
};

$scope.getValues = function(){
    $log.log('getValues was called.');
    var list = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.fields, function(value, index){
        //$log.log(item);
        $log.log(value);
        $log.log(index);
        this.push(value);
        //this.push(item);
    },list);
    return list;
};

});
```

This example is working like I want it too, but it is not using ng-repeat.

http://jsfiddle.net/webmandman/Ls4g4yLn/13/

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
    <span>{{values.join(',')}}</span><br>
    <input ng-repeat="field in fields" type="text" name="{{field.name}}" ng-model="field.text"/>
</div>
<button ng-click="display()">display</button>

</div>
```

controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

angular.module('app').controller("myCtrl", function($log,$scope, $http) {
$scope.fields = [
    {name:"Name", text:null},
    {name:"Phone", text:null}
];

$scope.display = function(){
  $log.log("display has been called...");
  $scope.values = $scope.getValues()
};

$scope.getValues = function(){
    var list = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.fields, function(value, index){
        //$log.log(item);
        $log.log(value);
        $log.log(index);
        this.push(value.text);
        //this.push(item);
    },list);
    return list;
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your `$scope.values`, you push refercnes to your `$scope.fields`, hence then when you edit a field text, it is rendered in both places.

Instead, you can simply push the text in your values, as `String` are passed by copy and not reference (that's pure Javascript not related to Angular).

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zrwq6cmu/